# Store overlapping regions in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to implement an optimal way so as to store regions in mat after doing a connection an it comes up this question: which is the best way to store the following overlapped information?

I have this region in which all the pixels are at 255 in a CV_8U1C mat.

[image]

Next, the following connection is done and I got this CV_32S1C mat where the red pixels equal 1 and the green ones 2.

[image]

Now I want to vectorize the closing operation and apply it to every connection region. For instance, a closing with EE circle of 50px. Obtaining the following results:

[image]
[image]

Which is the best way to store information in the same mat as the following way?

[image]

This is just an example of what I am trying to implement. I know that one option would be to set every region in a different channel, however, that will not be efficient and fast for 10.000 regions or more as an example.